# Why can't i enter a LoadBalancerProbe into my ServiceDefinition File?

Tags: azure, load-balancing

iam trying to setUp a CustomLoadBalancerProbe for my Azure Service.

according to this information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj151530.aspx#LoadBalancerProbes

It should be possible to add a  Tag to the service definition file.
but when i try this i only get a message saying that it is an invalid emelent for the servicedefinition file.

then i googled a little and found this : http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/how-to-load-balance-virtual-machines/

here it tells me that the load balancing for virtual machines is only available in the preview version of azure.

So iam a little confused now:

1) is there a difference between the load balancing for VMs and the usage of loadbalancing probes as described in the schema? (link 1)

2) if no: Is it just not supported yet?

3) if yes: Why cant i enter the probe into the service definition file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The LoadBalancerProbes element is only supported in version 1.7 (or higher) of the SDK. Now, the tricky part of it is that you need to add it before you define the Web/Worker Roles. So like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="WindowsAzure6" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2012-10.1.8">
  <LoadBalancerProbes>
    <LoadBalancerProbe name="MyProbe" protocol="http" intervalInSeconds="300" path="/something.aspx" port="80" timeoutInSeconds="30" />
  </LoadBalancerProbes>
  <WebRole name="WebRole1" vmsize="Small">
    ...
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

If you add it after the definition of your Web/Worker Roles, you'll get an "invalid child element" error in Visual Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="WindowsAzure6" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2012-10.1.8">
  <WebRole name="WebRole1" vmsize="Small">
    ...
  </WebRole>
  <LoadBalancerProbes>
    <LoadBalancerProbe name="MyProbe" protocol="http" intervalInSeconds="300" path="/something.aspx" port="80" timeoutInSeconds="30" />
  </LoadBalancerProbes>
</ServiceDefinition>
```